# What are the requirements for the Mark VI helmet in Halo: Reach?

Tags: halo-reach

According to [halo.wikia.com](http://halo.wikia.com) the Mark VI helmet in Halo: Reach costs 300,000 credits. However does anyone know what rank you must be to purchase it? Thank you.

**The helmet you wear, not the 2D icon:**
[image]

Comment: While this question is fine, the answers read like the sort of nonsense that has circulated through middle schools about HOW TO UNLOCK THE SECRET POKEMON for the past ten years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, now according to the Halo Wiki the Mark VI helmet costs 300,000 cR and is unlocked at Brigadier, which itself requires 1,400,000  total credits. I suppose next month we'll see if that's accurate.

Comment: I hit Colonel last week (the rank before Brigadier), and the Mark VI helmet showed up in the Armory, and it does indeed require the rank of Brigadier. It costs 300,000 cR.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read on various (modding) community sites the Mark VI helmet unlocks at the "Commander" rank, a rank past the current level cap of Lt. Colonel. This is purely speculation, but I'm guessing (based on the way the ranks have progressed so far) the next few ranks will be as follows:

---

Lt. Colonel

- Lt. Colonel Grade 1
- Lt. Colonel Grade 2
- Lt. Colonel Grade 3

[Commander](http://i56.photobucket.com/albums/g198/x372159/IMG_0167.jpg)        <---( Mark VI Helmet Unlocked )

- [Commander Grade 1 (w/ Picture)](http://i56.photobucket.com/albums/g198/x372159/IMG_0168.jpg)
- [Commander Grade 2 (w/ Picture)](http://i56.photobucket.com/albums/g198/x372159/IMG_0170.jpg)
- [Commander Grade 3 (w/ Picture)](http://i56.photobucket.com/albums/g198/x372159/IMG_0171.jpg)

Colonel

- Colonel Grade 1
- Colonel Grade 2
- Colonel Grade 3

---

UPDATED - Based on the newest information supplied by [Gary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3775/gary) on his last post! Commander is actually the next rank past Lt. Colonel Grade 3... We'll have that Mark VI soon!

Answer (score -1):

Apparently it's reserved for people who have played all the LIVE enabled games in the series. You need to have 4 nameplates from the first 4 Halo games and the Reach Beta.

> Reserved for our most steadfast fans.
>   Unlock four of the five nameplates
>   Halo PC, Halo 2, Halo 3, Halo 3: ODST,
>   or the Halo: Reach Beta to earn the
>   Master Chief's MJOLNIR Mk VI helmet
>   nameplate.

Read more: [IGN boards](http://boards.ign.com/halo/b5240/195623208/p1/#ixzz10RZGkoAzBlockquotenameplate.)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I mean the helmet, not the nameplate.

Comment: Ah, apologies.  From what I've read about the Mark VI helmet, the general consensus is that it's going to be available once Bungie add more ranks to the game.

Comment: No need to apologize. I guess we'll have to wait until they raise the limit hopefully next month. Thanks.